# I want to go to a new line every time a \n appears in a given string

Tags: java, arrays, string

Im making a programm that takes a string as a parameter and if it reads in a \n value it will skip too a new line however for some reason java doesnt recognise '\n' i want to replace all occurences of \n with ! so that i can use a char array to do the new line thing but the replace all doesnt work when i plug in \n any ideas how i can fix my issue

```
  public void newLine(String gg) {
     int temp = 0;
      String x = gg.replaceAll("\n", "!");
      for(char pp: x.toCharArray()) {
          if(pp == '!') {
              System.out.println();
          }
          System.out.printf("%s",pp);
      }
  }
```

'''

Comment: Can you add example of input and output and explain what is wrong with output?

Comment: By `\n`, do you mean a newline character or do you mean a literal backslash then an `n`?

Comment: Your entire code could be reduce to `System.out.print(gg.replace("\\n", "\n"))` if you replaced a literal `\n` with an actual line break and wouldn't break if there are `!` in `gg` already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` is a newline character, but you want to replace the character sequence of a literal backslash then an `n`, which in java is coded as `"\\n"` (you must escape the escape character).

Escape the backslash and use `replace()`:

```
gg = gg.replace("\\n", "!");
```

---

Note that `replace()` replaces all occurrences, but `replaceAll()` uses regex to match whereas `replace()` matches literally.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that in Java, strings are immutable. Additionally, using a for each loop uses a copy of every element in an iterable object. I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, but this method replaces every newline escape seqeuence with an exclamation mark and prints the result.

```
public void newLine (String gg) {
    String[] ggArray = gg.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < ggArray.length; i++) {
        ggArray[i] = ggArray[i].replace("\n", "!");
    }
    gg = String.join(" ", ggArray);
    System.out.println(gg);
}
```

Comment: thanks for help ill maybe redownload my ide cause i tried a similar thing as abover and my input This\\nis\\na\\nString\\non\\ndifferent\\nlines stays the exact same when i expect to have '!' instead of "\n"

Comment: You don't need to split then join. Just `gg = gg.replace("\n", "!");` gives the same result, which OP has already tried.